# Posting images from src to server

Tags: jquery, django, html, django-views

I have a form like below, want to post image file from src of img, what should I do?

```
<form style="width: 205px; height: 205px; float: left;" method="post" action="/3/edit_profile/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="uw4rYSsp...">
    <img id="cropped_0" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBO...">
</form>
```

Comment: You can set a hidden form field to have the value of the img `src`

Comment: I have image with source "data:image/png;base64..." can I send it to Django view?

Comment: A standard form submit does not submit anything other than `input` type fields so you will need to either prevent the submit, get the `src` of the `img` and assign it to a new `<input type="hidden" value="put the src value here"/> and then resubmit the form or alternatively do an AJAX `post` with similar characteristics, whereby you send the `src` as a post variable

Comment: I want its image not its src to post to the view and save it to database

Comment: Listen, you have to send the `src`, decode it or do whatever you have to do on your back-end to store it and give it the URL you want.  That is the only way unless you use a `<input type="file"/>` field?  You choose, it's all possible but you need to work within certain constraints!  Otherwise I suggest you change your question as myself and others aren't properly understanding and wasting your and our time.

Answer (score 0):

So I think you want to store the image in the database. For that you can pass `src` of the image to your django view(using hidden input). Then in django view

```
import requests
img = requests.get(src)
```

Then you can access the image content by `img.content` and store it in the database

Comment: I want to save image to database and have url corresponded to it (e.g. www.example.com/image.png), not url format like "data:image/png;base64" in order to be accessed for everyone.

Comment: Please specify exactly what you want to do in question itself